# setIndexOptions(IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS):not applicable for arguments

Tags: java

```
public MyIndexWriter( String dataType ) throws IOException {
    if (dataType.equals("trectext")) {
        directory = FSDirectory.open(new File(Classes.Path.IndexTextDir));  
    } else {
        directory = FSDirectory.open(new File(Classes.Path.IndexWebDir)); 
    }
    IndexWriterConfig indexConfig=new IndexWriterConfig(null, new       WhitespaceAnalyzer(null));
    indexConfig.setMaxBufferedDocs(10000);
    ixwriter = new IndexWriter( directory, indexConfig);
    type = new FieldType();
    type.setIndexOptions(IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS);
    type.setStored(false);
    type.setStoreTermVectors(true);
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem:      The method setIndexOptions(FieldInfo.IndexOptions) in the
>   type FieldType is not applicable for the arguments (IndexOptions)

So how should I deal with "type.setIndexOptions(IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS);"?

Comment: As it is a compilation error check your setIndexOptions's aruguments

Comment: Thanks, I check the setIndexOptions and find the problem.